# Creating a Google Doc from a template with tables in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, placeholder

This is a Google Apps Script to create a Google Doc from a template and the values in a Google Spreadsheet.

It takes the fields from the active row in your Google Spreadsheet (the one with a highlighted cell or row) and using a Google Doc template (identified by TEMPLATE_ID) creates a doc with these fields replacing the placeholders in the template.
The place-holders are identified by having % around them, e.g. %Name%. It is run using the custom “Create Document” menu that is created in the sheet.

Now, my question is, if I have also a table, with the normal placeholders, (see the image or the link) how could I proceed if I put also the placeholder %Table 1% in the doc template?

[image]

In this case, the placeholders %Name%, %Surname%, %Fruit% have to take the values only from the second row. The placeholder %Table 1% have to take the values until the end of the table (row 5).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l3bCuyRnz_ylMHMfhbRC-_L5bLkWwEkrzGKgy46Kvnk/edit?usp=sharing

```
function myfunction() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var TEMPLATE_ID = 'xxx';
    //var TEMPLATE_ID = ss.getRange("TEMPLATEID").getValue();
     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {
        
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs')
        return
      }
      
      var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
          copyId = copyFile.getId(),
          copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
           var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(copyFile.getId()); // Get Document as File
      
          var FILE_NAME = ui.prompt('Insert file name:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
          FILE_NAME.getSelectedButton() == ui.ButtonSet.OK
          copyDoc.setName(FILE_NAME.getResponseText())
          
      var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection(),
          activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
          numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
          activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(),
          activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
          headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
          columnIndex = 0
        
      for (;columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {
          var nextValue = formatString(activeRow[0][columnIndex])
          copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%', nextValue)                         
        }
      
      copyDoc.saveAndClose()
      
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('File doc created!!')
      
    }
```

Comment: Considering that you are usually only using data from a single row, would this table have a single row, or it would take all rows of data for those three columns?

Comment: Simply, like in this case, the placeholders %Name%, %Surname%, %Fruit% have to take the values only from the second row. The placeholder %Table 1% have to take the values until the end of the table (row 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Define which columns correspond to table data. In the sample below (that's done via `tableColumn` in the sample below, where the first value corresponds to the first table column, and the second value corresponds to the last column).
- When iterating through the sheet columns, check whether the column corresponds to table values. If it doesn't, just make the same actions as in your original code. If it does:
- Get all values related to those columns (`tableValues`).
- Use [findText(searchPattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern) to get the element where `%Table 1% placeholder exists.
- Use [getChildIndex](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getChildIndex(Element)) to get the index of the element where this placeholder exists, and to remove that element's text (the placeholder).
- Use [insertTable(childIndex, cells)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-cells) to insert the table at the specified index, using the source values.

#### Code sample:

```
function myfunction() {
  var tableColumn = [3,5]; // Table header is in column C to E
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var TEMPLATE_ID = 'xxx';
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {        
    ui.alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs')
    return
  }
  var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy();
  var copyId = copyFile.getId();
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  var FILE_NAME = ui.prompt('Insert file name:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  copyDoc.setName(FILE_NAME.getResponseText());
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getBody();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var activeRowIndex = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var activeRow = sheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues()[0];
  var headerRow = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues()[0];
  for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < headerRow.length; columnIndex++) {
    if (columnIndex === tableColumn[0] - 1) { // Check if column corresponds to table data
      try {
        var tableValues = sheet.getRange(2, tableColumn[0], sheet.getLastRow()-1,tableColumn[1]-tableColumn[0]+1).getValues();
        var placeholder = `%${headerRow[tableColumn[0]-1]}%`;
        var rangeElement = copyBody.findText(placeholder);
        var element = rangeElement.getElement();
        console.log(element.asText().getText())
        var childIndex = copyBody.getChildIndex(element.getParent());
        console.log(childIndex)
        const elementText = copyBody.getChild(childIndex).asText().getText();
        const [beforeText, afterText] = elementText.split(placeholder);
        copyBody.getChild(childIndex).asText().setText('');
        copyBody.insertParagraph(childIndex, beforeText);
        copyBody.insertTable(childIndex+1, tableValues);
        copyBody.insertParagraph(childIndex+2, afterText);
      } catch(err) {
        continue;
      }
    } else if (columnIndex < tableColumn[0] - 1 || columnIndex > tableColumn[1] - 1) {
      var nextValue = formatString(activeRow[columnIndex]);
      copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[columnIndex] + '%', nextValue);
    }                     
  }
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('File doc created!!')     
}
```

Comment: Hello. I have created the template with all the placeholders (%Name%, %Surname%, %Fruit% %Table 1%) then I have tried your script, but when I have activated the script after selecting the row 2, in the doc generated, I have found only the table, and not the other fields (%Name%, %Surname%, %Fruit%). Why?

Comment: In addition, if in the template I have other text, your script delete everything... Why?
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DNLmFX7puA6rXJhR1ATA9PwFbzp0bcnhm2v4rIb9hz4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Gavis For some reason the template you shared only includes two [elements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element) (two paragraphs), with the second paragraph spanning all context from `Name` up to `%Fruit%`. Since the code deletes all previous element content, it deletes all that text too. That is, the placeholder should be in a separate element.

Comment: @Gavis In any case, I'm updating my answer with an alternative that keeps the other text in the element by retrieving it and creating 3 new elements (before table, table, and after table). That workaround removes previous formatting of the text in that element, so I really recommend modifying the source template to make sure the table placeholder is in a separate element, no shared by additional text. I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: @lamblichus If I would to add 2 tables? How I must to edit in yor code?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70998914/creating-a-google-doc-with-2-tables-in-google-apps-script